# Error inflating MapView

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview, android-inflate

I'm trying to show a MapView inside a Fragment and I get an error when I inflate it:

```
    03-21 14:34:44.234 32691-32691/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners, PID: 32691
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)                                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)                                                                                                at com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners.Fragments.NuevaCarreraFragment.onCreateView(NuevaCarreraFragment.java:53)                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)                                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)                                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/AbstractSafeParcelable;                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)                                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)                                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)                                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)                                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)                                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)                                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)                                                                                                   at com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners.Fragments.NuevaCarreraFragment.onCreateView(NuevaCarreraFragment.java:53)                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    03-21 14:34:44.234 32691-32691/com.example.javiersanzrozalen.fatrunners E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                    ... 27 more
```

Any idea ? This is the XML where I place my MapView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.NuevaCarreraFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

Finally solved it compiling the last version of Google Maps library recommended.

Comment: can you put the xml file

Comment: Already edited !